# USB Devices Keep Disconnecting (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, usb

I recently got a new computer along with a usb wifi adapter and it keeps disconnecting and reconnecting at random.  Sometimes it is just rapid disconnect reconnect and others it is when I do something big like play a game online.  Also, when I plug in a new USB device all my devices disconnect.  I have tried fiddling power saving options and disabling selective spending.  I have also gone into device manager to not allow my devices to be shut off to save power.  I even purchased a powered usb hub.  Nothing has worked.

Comment: Try this : Windows Key + R -> cmd -> netsh int tcp set global chimney=disabled

Comment: "when I plug in a new USB device all my devices disconnect" - this is a serious system blow. Even a mouse? Could you share with us what is your "a new computer", which processor/bridge is used for USB, which "a usb wifi adapter", give at least SOME information about your system. A picture (or full report) from USBview.exe will help.